# declaration of variable of this kind "int (*pfds)[2];" what they are called

Tags: c

I was looking into simple source code. and found this line

```
 int (*pfds)[2];
```

does it means pointer to function similar to

```
     void (*fun_ptr)()[2] = &fun;
```

which I think is array of pointer to function `fun(void)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int (*pfds)[2];` is a pointer to an array with two elements.

The parentheses are there because `int *pfds[2];` would be an array of two pointers, as in `char *argv[]` being an array of char pointers (i.e. strings).

A function pointer `void (*fun_ptr)()` has a second set of parentheses which is used for the argument list: `int (*add)(int x, int y)`.

It doesn't seem `void (*fun_ptr)()[2]` or `void *fun_ptr()` would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

`int (*pfds)[2];`---->      `pfds` is a pointer to an array of 2 elements.

`void (*fun_ptr)()[2]`---->  Declare `fun_ptr` as pointer to function returning array of 2 elements of void. But it is invalid.  Since, in C, function returning array is not allowed.

`void* (*fun_ptr)()` -----> declare `fun_ptr` as pointer to function returning, pointer to void. This is valid.  This is what you need, if you want to return an array of  type void.

Comment: A function can not return an array